# TypeORM cannot find entities if entity directory was not set in configuration files

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with the fallowing configuration file: ormconfig.json

```
{
"type": "mysql",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 3306,
"username": "root",
"password": "my-secret-pw",
"database": "mytestdb",
}
```

My Entities files are stored on the ./src/bar/entity directory.
I always get the following error:

> RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "myTable" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

The Entity is found when I manually add the directory to the configuration file:

```
{
...
"entities": ["src/bar/entity/**/*.ts"]
}
```

My Entity is defined like:

```
@Entity('myTable')
export default class MyTable {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;
    ...
```

How can I allow the TypeORM to find those entities without setting manually in the configuration file for each directory?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The most common case you described is to have separate `entities` directory which consists only of Entity declarations.

```
{
...
"entities": ["src/bar/entities/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Another approach would be importing each entity separately:

```
import {User} from "./payment/entity/User";
import {Post} from "./blog/entity/Post";

{
...
"entities": [User, Post]
}
```

Comment: The second option is not possible using a configuration file, am I correct?. How can i load those entities separately?

Comment: I think you mean it's not possible with `ormconfig.json` just declare the file as `ormconfig.js` which module.exports the config object. http://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-ormconfigjs

Comment: It makes nosense to have different floders for enties if you divided projects into app.

Normally If project gonna huge I will prefer to make db as seperate mini-project and have my all entities in one entity folder only. and sub divide that entity folder according to app name

Answer (score 23):

For me it helped to include also `src` directory to `ormconfig.json`:

```
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}",
    "src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
  ],
```

Comment: simplifying {src, dist}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}

Comment: It showed the following error in me `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 10):

For me the answer was 

`{
 ...
 entities: [join(__dirname, '/../**/**.entity{.ts,.js}')],
}`

I've found the exapmle here
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/05-sql-typeorm/src/app.module.ts

Comment: For me, removing the slash like so: `${__dirname}../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}` made it work. I'm the project in a monorepo, so that might be why it was needed in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to put all entities in the same place (ie if you have module folders and want to put entities in their associated module folders), and if you are using a file naming convention like `foo.entity.ts`, `foo.service.ts`, etc. then you can do the following and it will find all entities wherever they are in your source tree:

```
{
  ...
  "entities": ["src/**/*{.entity.ts}"],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Nest.js in order to work for both development and production environment, I had to do like this:

```
entities: [
   this.isProduction() ? 
       path.join(__dirname, '../**/**.entity{.ts,.js}') : '**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
],

// ....

private isProduction(): boolean {
    const mode = this.configService.get('NODE_ENV');
    return mode !== 'development';
}
```

Comment: interesting -- why was this necessary

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my users entity file was in lowercase, when I capitalised it - all worked.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```js
entities: [
  path.join(
    __dirname,
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ?
    '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}' :
    '/**/*.entity.js', // afaik building stuffs are js-only
  ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To take advantage of the Nest.JS modularization, one can use the [auto-load entities](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities) feature.

The entities in this way can be placed within the respective module folder keeping the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

To enable it, set the `autoLoadEntities: true` property of the TypeOrm configuration object once.

Just do:

```js
//app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then module entities should be registered through the `forFeature()`.

```js
//user.module.ts
@Module({
  
  imports: [
      /* Here, User and ForgotPasswordToken entities are being registered */
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, ForgotPasswordToken])
  ],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

The entities that aren't registered through `forFeature()` method won't be included.

For more details, see [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities).

Comment: This just saved me several hours. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
/../**/*.entity.{ts,js}
```

It works for me. Basically, in dist, it's looking for the entity. but in the config I gave ts, that's why it did not work. make sure you added both ts and js extension

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that the name of the entity file is not plural. For example if you're creating a post entity file, it should not be "posts.entity.ts" instead it should be "post.entity.ts"